# Ask all permissions during app installation on API > 23

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Since android M the only way to ask permissions is to do so ant runtime but VK client app somehow manages to ask all of its permissions upon installation on all android versions. Below is a screenshot from pixel phone. Can anyone tell me how is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but in order to preserve backwards compability, "older" apps can still ask permissions at install. Only newer apps (targeted at higher versions) have to do it at runtime.

Comment: the runtime code seems abit strange for new developers....

Answer (score 6):

They use targetSdkVersion lower than 23:

"If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the app requests permissions from the user at run-time [...] If the device is running Android 5.1.1 (API level 22) or lower, or the app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower, the system asks the user to grant the permissions when the user installs the app"

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I know about this hack but it means that the app will be in compatibility mode. Isn't it bad? Plus all the new api's that can't be used...

Comment: Let's say I would never use that, if you ask me, I would strongly discourage it. But at the end of the day, it depends what you're trying to accomplish. Asking permissions at runtime is quite simple, so it shouldn't be avoided.

Comment: If I am not wrong facebook app has still less than 23

Comment: This answer is no longer satisfactory, as of November 2018, Google Play will not accept APKs with a targetSdkVersion less than 26. Therefore this solution of targeting <23 is no longer possible. How can we request permissions at install time with targetSdkVersion > 23??? Let me guess, it's impossible? Google have really made a huge mistake here. Our apps are not for commercial end users, they are business tools. We do not want the end user to have *any* control over app permissions whatsoever.

Comment: @JeneralJames this part "as of November 2018, Google Play will not accept APKs with a targetSdkVersion less than 26" is not fully true, in the sense that Google Play will not accept to publish a new apk with target sdk version less than 26, or update an existing one ... but if someone has an apk already published, and doesn't update it anymore, it still be valid and running as of November 2018.

Comment: @JeneralJames "We do not want the end user to have any control over app permissions whatsoever" -> luckily between your app and me as a user, there is the os / android system ... of course, as a user, but also as a developer, I want to give the user all control over app permissions, because I want her to know what I'm requesting to her, and why, so that she can deny that to me (and especially to you) if it doesn't seem legit ... for instance a calculator app doesn't need to read my phone number, have access to my contacts, read my wifi, and so on

Comment: @Alessio in lower android versions, the user was informed about permissions needed and he /she had the choice to accept or not those permissions, i.e. with app installation. Right now there is no way for a developer to define a minimum permission set that the app absolutely requires, otherwise your support team will be overloaded with calls. For most business apps that is a huge problem. 
Users don't want to listen to your/mine instructions on how to allow required permissions because they accidentally have clicked "deny".

Comment: @daneejela I'm completely missing your point, sorry. I was answering one SO question, which was "how is this possible" and I explained how it is possible with my answer. I didn't make any comment about it been right or even suggesting that to be used (quite the opposite, as the system prevents it), neither about what the users want, because unless you measure it, is very difficult to say what they want a-priori. Personally I would never limit my target sdk version, and it's anyhow something that no one can keep on the long run. So, what's the point of your comment? Please let me know

Comment: @Alessio, I am sorry if my comment sounded offensive, I was trying to solve the same problem as the author of the question and I was annoyed with lack of possibility to define this minimum required permission set that app absolutely relies on.  
So, the point of my comment was to argue that there is a real case scenario where there is a valid reason to enforce permissions at the install time. By "enforce" I mean give the user a choice either to grant that permission and install the app or not install the app at all.

Comment: @daneejela no offense taken, I was just trying to figure it out what you meant :) definitely it's a trick, a workaround, and you'll be fighting against the system, so it makes no sense from any point of view to enforce such an approach. Even as an user, I would rather prefer an app that would allow me the freedom to handle single permissions at runtime, and not the all-or-one permissions suggested here. If you're asked by some PO as a developer's requirement, well, bring it up that it makes no sense, even if technically possible and difficultly maintainable

Comment: @daneejela on the other hand what you can do is: define a set of permissions that are *mandatory* for your app to work minimally, and another set for *optional* permissions. Then after splash screen use a permission screen to ask them all, and let the user to proceed to registration flow or rest of the app only if at least mandatory are met. Ask optional at runtime, and everytime one mandatory is disabled prompt the same permission screen to gather them again. I implemented it and it works like a charm, I guarantee that's the best approach you can have with handling Android permissions

Comment: @Alessio, thank you, it makes very much sense to implement it in the way you described in your second comment. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

It just seems the app was not updated to comply with API level >= 23. You can manage differently asking permissions depending on the API level targeted.

> If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the app requests permissions from the user at run-time. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, so the app needs to check whether it has the permissions every time it accesses permission-protected APIs. For more information about requesting permissions in your app, see the Working with System Permissions training guide.
>
> If the device is running Android 5.1.1 (API level 22) or lower, or the app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower, the system asks the user to grant the permissions when the user installs the app. If you add a new permission to an updated version of the app, the system asks the user to grant that permission when the user updates the app. Once the user installs the app, the only way they can revoke the permission is by uninstalling the app.

[Requesting Permissions API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are classified as : Normal permissions or dangerous permissions

-Normal permissions : don't pose much risk to the user's privacy  or the device's operation. if your app lists normal permissions in its manifest the system automatically grants those permissions to your app at install time(the system does not prompt the user to grant normal permissions , and user can't revoke them).

-dangerous permissions : these permissions could potentially affect the user's privacy or the device's normal operation , the user must explicity agree to grant those permissions.
Only dangerous permissions require user agreement.
But the way Android asks the user to grant dangerous permissions depends on 2 things :

1)Version of android running on the user device
2)The system version targeted by the app (targetSdkVersion)

- if the device is running Android 6.0(API level 23) or higher , and the app 'targetSdkVersion' is 23 or higher, the user will not be notifiy of any app permissions at install time, your app must ask the user to grant the dangerous permissions at runtime (see the documentation for how to request permissions and check it).
- if the device is running Android 5.1.1 (API level 22) or lower , or the app 'targetSdkVersion' is 22 or lower , the system automatically asks the user to grant all dangerous permissions for your app at install time

Comment: i just wondering.... why don't we just keep using the api level 22 for the easiest steps?